# Nested Queries/ JOIN IN SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Question: List the name of the team and number of wins of all teams that had more wins than the
average team had.  Order results by descending number of wins.

```
SELECT mlb_team.name, mlb_team.wins, AVG(mlb_team.wins)
FROM mlb_team
GROUP BY mlb_team.name
HAVING mlb_team.wins > AVG(mlb_team.wins);
```

My current solution is giving me the error Error Code: 1055. Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'comp3421.mlb_team.wins' which is not functionally dependent o.

Comment: `GROUP BY` will require every column that is not aggregated.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT mlb_team.name, SUM(mlb_team.wins)
FROM mlb_team
GROUP BY mlb_team.name
HAVING SUM(mlb_team.wins) > AVG(mlb_team.wins)
ORDER BY SUM(mlb_team.wins) DESC;
```

Note: I am not familiar with mysql but largely this is how it should be.

Answer (score 0):

`GROUP BY` requires every column that is not aggregated.

In your code, the `GROUP BY` expects `mlb_team.name` and `mlb_team.wins`, not just `mlb_team.name`.

Here is the code:

```
SELECT mlb_team.name, mlb_team.wins, AVG(mlb_team.wins)
FROM mlb_team
GROUP BY mlb_team.name,mlb_team.wins
HAVING mlb_team.wins > AVG(mlb_team.wins);
```